# Need this basic ansible variables explaination

Tags: ansible

I know this is really really basic question, but I really want the explanation of this:

```
repos:
  - name: 'EPEL'
    url: 'http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm'
    key: 'http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/fedora/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6'
  - name: 'RPMForge'
    url: 'http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm'
    key: 'http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt'
  - name: 'Remi'
    url: 'http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm'
    key: 'http://rpms.famillecollet.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi'
  - name: 'Webtatic'
    url: 'http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm'
    key: 'http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/RPM-GPG-KEY-webtatic-andy'
```

Like what is "repo", I think it's the list? but what is the "name", "url" and "key"? and why only "name" has the "-" infront of it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/YAMLSyntax.html

Comment: @MarcB thanks, I didn't get it there, that's why I have raised this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps it helps if you look at it in terms of `python` `dict` and `list`:

```
$ python -c "

import yaml
import pprint

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=3);
x = yaml.load('''repos:
  - name: 'EPEL'
    url: 'http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm'
    key: 'http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/fedora/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6'
  - name: 'RPMForge'
    url: 'http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm'
    key: 'http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt'
  - name: 'Remi'
    url: 'http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm'
    key: 'http://rpms.famillecollet.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi'
  - name: 'Webtatic'
    url: 'http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm'
    key: 'http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/RPM-GPG-KEY-webtatic-andy'
''');
pp.pprint( x );"

{  'repos': [  {  'key': 'http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/fedora/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6',
                  'name': 'EPEL',
                  'url': 'http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm'},
               {  'key': 'http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt',
                  'name': 'RPMForge',
                  'url': 'http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm'},
               {  'key': 'http://rpms.famillecollet.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi',
                  'name': 'Remi',
                  'url': 'http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm'},
               {  'key': 'http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/RPM-GPG-KEY-webtatic-andy',
                  'name': 'Webtatic',
                  'url': 'http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm'}]}
$
```

so:

- `repos` is an element (key) in a `dict`
- value for key `repos` is a `list` of `dicts`

> why only "name" has the "-" infront of it?

Invalid question. That's YAML syntax, when you want to declare a `dict`, that's how you do it.

O and as Marc said read: [ansible YAML Syntax](http://docs.ansible.com/YAMLSyntax.html)

Comment: thanks for an excellent explanation, nothing is "Invalid question" as long as you ask it for betterment.